# How kernel interacts with the processor ?

Tags: linux, kernel, processor

How kernel or Boot loader interacts with the processor ? How they modify the register values ? Done a lot of searching but couldn't find the proper basic answer. I am a kernel newbie please someone help me to understand this basic question by explaining the detailed process flow.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: how a particular data from the software is loaded into memory  ?

Comment: What data are you talking about?

Comment: How signal transformation takes place from software to hardware ?

Comment: "signal transformation from software to hardware"... Wow, that's pretty low-level. You may need to look for an electrical engineering or CPU design forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write an OS read "Operating Systems Design and Implementation" by Tenenbaum. Linus Torvalds read it, and wrote Linux afterwards.